# List Division in Period Folding

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, period

I have two lists of x and y values, respectively (~200k coordinate pairs total) representative of a sinusoidal wave. It's period ends at the 300th coordinate point; I've been tasked with dividing the lists by period (so ~700 separate lists of x/y values) and plotting the individual waves atop each other (period folding).

I don't know why, but I'm hitting a damn wall. I wouldn't even know what code to provide you guys with to scrutinize, nothing's working and I'm evidently doing something wrong. Just some general guidance on whatever for-loop setup or NumPy method to use to divide these guys into intervals of 300 and store them in their own list would be heavily appreciated.

Comment: So you have a big list and you want to divide it into many "chunks" of 300 items each?  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/494134

Comment: Why two lists instead of one list of pairs?